# Annihilator of $a'$ and $b'$ in the ring $\mathbb{Z}/(a'b')$ ?

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

I want to find the annihilator of $a'$ and $b'$ of the quotient ring $R=\mathbb{Z}/(a'b')$ where $a',\,b'>1$.

So if I go by the definition, $ann(a')=\{r\in\mathbb{R}\mid a'r=0\}=\{a'\mathbb{Z}+b'\mathbb{Z}+(a'\,b')\in\mathbb{R}\mid a'(a'\mathbb{Z}+b'\mathbb{Z})=0\}$

Am I correct unto this point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there are a couple of problems.

First of all, the $r\in \Bbb R$ part is not right (maybe just a typo?) It should read

$ann(a')=\{x\in\mathbb{Z}/(a'b')\mid (a'+(a'b'))x=0\}$

Secondly, it looks like you're misunderstanding the last part. If I were to rewrite the whole line, I would write this:

$$ann(a')=\{x\in\mathbb{Z}/(a'b')\mid (a'+(a'b'))x=0\}=\{z+(a'\,b')\mid (z+(a'\,b'))(a'+(a'b'))=0+(a'b')\}$$

Rewriting the expression on the far right again, we're trying to determine when $(z+(a'\,b'))(a'+(a'b'))=za'+(a'b')=0+(a'b')$. The last equality happens iff $za'\in (a'b')$.

Then $za'\in (a'b')$ implies $za'=a'b'c$ for some $c\in \Bbb Z$. Cancelling $a'$ from both sides, we arrive at $z=b'c$. Thus $z\in (b')$. So anything that annihilates $a'+(a'b')$ must lie in $(b')+(a'b')$.

Conversely, it's obvious that anything in $(b')+(a'b')$ annihilates $a'+(a'b')$.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. I understood everything. The last line should be, "Conversely, it's obvious that anything in $(b')+(a'b')$ annihilates $a'+(a'b')$". Isn't? :)

Comment: @LinearAlgebra Great, glad it helped! Sorry, I can't see what you're getting at about the last line. What specific piece of the sentence are you asking about?

Comment: No sorry. I think I had some confusion. Thinking about this problem for too long made me confused I guess. :) Thank you so much for all your help, I really appreciate it. :)

Comment: @LinearAlgebra Great! Glad to hear it. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

${\rm mod}\ ab\!:\ ax \equiv 0 \iff ab\mid ax \iff b\mid x,\ $ so $\,\ {\rm ann}(a) = (b)\,$ in $\,\Bbb Z/(ab)\ \ $ **QED**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. :) Your answer is really condensed. I will read and re-read it to try to understand it. :)

Comment: @LinearAlgebra It's meant to be a condensed, high-level view of the proof using more familiar congruence notation. If you expand it to quotient ring notation using cosets you will obtain something similar to rschwieb's answer. But this high-level view may appeal to your intuition gained from practice with modular arithmetic, so may help guide you in constructing the proof.

Comment: Indeed. I hope one day I will be as talented as you to come up with these kind of proofs. :)

Comment: @Linear These things become easy with practice. Be sure to understand the expanded version  in rschwieb's answer. After one has mastered the basics then one can write more concise versions (that often abuse notation), knowing with experience when it is safe to do so (and when not). Also, be sure to go back-and-forth between prior *concrete* examples such as modular arithmetic and the *abstract* notion of general quotient (or residue) rings. Concrete examples help build your intuition for the abstract objects. That was the point of this answer, to encourage you to go back-and-forth this way.